# Why does passing a pointer by reference after passing it by value point to the original memory location?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm working with SWIG to wrap some C++ code in Python. The C++ function I am wrapping is defined as:

```
template <typename T>
void getData(const std::string& fileName, T*& data);
```

Data is passed as a reference to a pointer because the data in the file can either be of the same type as the pointer or of a different type. In the former case we just replace the pointer with the one pointing to the file data, in the latter case we use std::copy to cast every value to the requested type.

Now we come to my question, the SWIG wrapping has given me the following function:

```
void wrap_getData(const std::string& fileName, T* data) {
     getData(fileName, data);
}
```

And this is called using:

```
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[dataSizeInFile]
wrap_getData(fileName, data)
```

As the data type in the file is also unsigned char, normally it would just change the pointer memory address (if I was using getData). However, now I would expect this not to happen, but it does.

As an example the original memory address of the pointer (&ptr) = 0x000000000c840070, then inside the wrap_getData function the data pointer memory address (&ptr) is 0x00000000002393e8, which is, as expected different, as the pointer is copied. But now, when I pass this pointer by reference to the actual getData function, the memory address (&ptr) is again 0x000000000c840070, which I would not expect, I would expect it to remain 0x00000000002393e8, as the copy is passed by reference. Why does this happen?

Comment: Please edit your question to more clearly define what you mean by "address" at any particular point. Using terms like "the address of the pointer" to mean `&ptr` and "the address the pointer points to" to mean simply `ptr`. Right now it's really unclear which you mean when, and which of the two values isn't what you expect.

Comment: Please go here and edit what you see to match what you're trying to explain:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61d21d0af7c9b1e2

Comment: PaulMcKenzie, I edited it, the behavior in the Coliru Viewer is indeed what I would expect (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5080224fe682ebe0), but is not the behavior I am seeing with Visual Studio 2012. So, I'm unsure why it is behaving as expected there and not on my system.

Comment: @Geert - Well, I have VS 2008 and VS 2013, and the behavior is the same as the Coliru example.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, you are right, I should have looked better. I figured out my own question, the reason this is working is just luck. I made a minimal example in Coliru to show this (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f09393b04b51926). When deleting the array in the getData function and immediately making a new one of the same size with new results in an array that uses the same memory location (try it by changing the 50 to 5). If I make a larger array, it no longer uses the same memory location and things fall apart. So as expected it is not supposed to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works by chance. If you delete an array and then immediately make a new one with exactly the same size the chance is high it will use the same memory address. The other behavior is as normal.

Answer (score 0):

you passed in the pointer. at the function, a new pointer was created but showing to the same object. and via the pointer, that object (to which the pointer was pointing to) was able to be changed in the function. after the function, the pointer, created with the function, was destroyed/freed. the original pointer's memory location stayed the same all the time, same as the value to which the pointer was pointing to.

that's what I think. I might have read your question too fast.

before you call `getData(fileName, data);` pointer `data` is for example on address "a_17" and it's value is for example "v_22", upon calling the function, function parameter `T*& data` gets created and gets the same value as the argument `data`. so it gets a new address (example "a_34") and it's value is "v_22".

if you want to change to where the pointer is pointing with a function, simply pass in a pointer to a pointer.

edit: added drawing:
[link](https://40.media.tumblr.com/6b9bcb9ee2fc465b0571280b7d42a9e8/tumblr_nlof79Vokd1s07qjfo2_r1_1280.png) this is how I see this. I admit I am new to this "*&" in the function parameters, I prefer using pointers and pointers to pointers.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. When I first pass the pointer (mem. adress a_17), a copy is made (mem. address a_18). When I pass this copy by reference, I expect this reference to show a_18, not a_17, correct?

Comment: having for example `char* data` then calling {{ `f_data(data);` where function is `void f_data(char*& in_data)` }} is same as with same `char* data` you would call {{ `f_data(&data);` which is void `f_data(char ** in_data)` but then you would have to use `*in_data` in the function. }}

function parameter"char*& in_data" means a reference to a pointer to a char. that means if we change in_data, we change data.

Comment: Hi iNyuu, sorry, I think we are not on the same page. Please see my comment in response to Paul McKenzie's comment, this contains code to what I would expect.